# Convert json request body to x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: json, api, content-type, x-www-form-urlencoded

If we have a request with json content type as follow

```
{"name":"user","var":"foo"}
```

The equivalent `x-www-form-urlencoded` will be `name=user&var=foo`

So, what will be the equivalent of `x-www-form-urlencoded` for:

```
{"name":"user","details":{"phone":"123","city":"newyork"},"Items":["123","456"]}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave your be in urlencoded this:

name=user&details[phone]=123&details[city]=newyork&Items=123,456